# HTML anchor tags not working in Firefox, Safari, iPad and iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, ipad, firefox, safari

My html anchor tags work in chrome and IE but in Firefox, Safari, iPad and iPhone they do not work, how come? and what can I do to fix it?

```
<a href="/services#underpinning">Underpinning</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

This is what I am trying to link it to on the `services` page:

```
<h1 id="#underpinning" name="underpinning">Underpinning</h1>
```

This is where I left off:

This is my link:

`<li><a href="/services#underpinning"><h2 id="underpinning">Underpinning<a href="services#underpinning"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-127" alt="home" src="http://powellgroupconstruction.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/home.jpg" width="500" height="337"></a></h2></a></li>`

This is where on my services page I want the link to goto:

`<a name="underpinning"><h1 id="underpinning" name="underpinning">Underpinning</h1></a>`

If I goto the url directly: http://powellgroupconstruction.com/services/#underpinning into safari or firefox, it works.

Comment: Perhaps the id should be "underpinning"?

Comment: @GarethAye Back in the old days (HTML 4.01) `id`s had to start with a letter [A-Za-z], see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html -- this is not true any more for HTML5. You could go for `id="#underpinning"` and then style it with `#\# { property: value; }`, see http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class for further special character examples. Although it's possible, it's definitely an error-prone approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.
On your example website you're using `HTML5 Doctype`, so I'm just answering respectively with HTML5 in mind:

1. **Forget about `name` attribute** in general and `<a name>` markup **as link target** in particular. 
   As the [HTML5 Candidate Recommendation spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) states: 
   *"An element's unique identifier can be used for a variety of purposes, most notably as a way to link to specific parts of a document using fragment identifiers, as a way to target an element when scripting, and as a way to style a specific element from CSS."* 
    That means, you can ***use any `id` as a link target***.
2. As Itay Gal has already stated in his answer, **don't use the same `id` more than once**. From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) again: 
   *"The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID)"*.
   That said, change your current code: 
   `<a id="underpinning" name="underpinning"><h1 id="underpinning" name="underpinning">Underpinning</h1></a>` 
   to 
   `<h1 id="underpinning">Underpinning</h1>`
3. You're using as link address currently `/services#underpinning`. As you're going with the WordPress rewrite functionality, entering `http://powellgroupconstruction.com/services` gets redirected to `http://powellgroupconstruction.com/services/`.
   Therefore you should **better put a slash at the end of your pages' names**, so the link address should be 
   `<a href="/services/#underpinning">Underpinning</a>`

Comment: This works in Firefox, Safari, iPhone and iPad, but not IE weird. what can i do to fix this in IE?

Comment: @user1269625 What version of IE do you use? Works for me in IE 8 `(8.0.6001.18702)`

Comment: #3 helped me solve the problem that my links did work everywhere except on my iPad. Even my iPhone worked, which was quite mysterious...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same id in multiple elements. The id needs to be unique, make sure you use each id only once and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Are href for both h2 and img tags are same? then have you tried this one:

```
    <a href="services#underpinning">
<h2 id="underpinning">Underpinning

<a href="services#underpinning"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-127"      alt="home" src="http://powellgroupconstruction.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/home.jpg"  width="500" height="337">
</a></h2>

    </a>
```

Answer (score -3):

I had an issue very similar to this. I believe your problem is that Firefox and Safari do not like an `<h2>` tag inside an anchor `<a>` tag. Try :

```
<a href="/services#underpinning"><span id="underpinning">Underpinning</span></a>
```

Comment: That doesn't have to do with browser liking or not liking things, if you're using HTML5 (with valid Doctype declaration), an anchor `<a>` can enclose block level elements like `<h2>` as well.