# Anchors in tables

Tags: html, css, html-table, anchor

I was trying to link a `table` with some anchors in the same page, but I don't know what's going on.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/shivatazo/6d6hseom/1/) it works as intended. But with [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/shivatazo/zyzghezc/) it doesn't work.

```
<table>
  <tr> </tr>
  <tr id="#i0">
    <td style="vertical-align:top"><a href="#section0">150, 166666</a></td>
    <td class="sec"><a href="#section0">PFC CINEMA LAMBRO</a><br>
      <font >Plan du radier et des fondation.</font><br>
      <br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="#i1">
    <td style="vertical-align:top"><a href="#section1">151, 165555</a></td>
    <td class="sec"><a href="#section1">AXONOMETRIA/CIMENTACIONES</a><br>
      <font >Projet pour un et des fondation.</font><br>
      <br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="#i2">
    <td style="vertical-align:top"><a href="#section2">152, 164444</a></td>
    <td class="sec"><a href="#section2">EXPO - MAD 2015</a><br>
      <font >Exposition des projets du semestre.</font><br>
      <br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="#i3">
    <td style="vertical-align:top"><a href="#section3">153, 163333</a></td>
    <td class="sec"><a href="#section3" onclick="closeNav()">PFC CINEMA LAMBRO</a><br>
      <font>Projet pour un cinéma à Milan.</font><br>
      <br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="Esp"></div>
<a href="#i3">This should make me go up</a>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Remove the # from the IDs `<tr id="i0">`

Comment: @Quentin: _"ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter (`[A-Za-z]`)"_... Well, in HTML4.

Comment: @Cerbrus — Who uses HTML 4 in 2016? From the same answer *HTML 5 is even more permissive, saying only that an id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters.*

Comment: Someone that prefers a strict set of rules for `ids`? ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus — Their preference doesn't make a difference to how browsers react.

Comment: From the accepted answer there: _"As a purely practical matter, you may want to avoid certain characters. Periods, colons and '#' have special meaning in CSS selectors..."_ <-- that does answer this question.

Comment: @Cerbrus — This isn't a CSS selector

Comment: @Cerbrus See interesting comment from Volker on how CSS can use #/#  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266675/html-anchor-tags-not-working-in-firefox-safari-ipad-and-iphone

Comment: @mplungjan — URLs are not CSS

Comment: @Quentin: You'd be better off avoiding `#` in `id` attributes for the same reason, though. Now you're just nitpicking to keep this open. The point is that, sure, `#` isn't forbidden, but it's very impractical. That's what the dupe target says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax for a fragment ID in a URL is a hash symbol followed by the ID of the element.

Your element IDs start with a hash symbol. So when `href="#id3"` looks for an element with `id="id3"`, it doesn't find it.

Remove the hash characters from the element IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work because you have used `#` both in your `id` and `href` attributes. Remove `#` from your `id`s and it will work.